# Why last added activityTest class launched firstly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, spoon

I am trying to launch activity from Splash activity-->Main activity...
1)created splashactivityTest
2)created mainActivirtTest

when testing started it launched from mainActivity ie:last added activity.why?

Comment: you are asking about the unit test rt?

Comment: About rt,i tried with many methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
Android Manifest

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity">

            <!-- move this code to the activity you want to launch first -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- move this code to the activity you want to launch first -->

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
```

Comment: this for app launching not for test app launching

Answer (score 0):

Using `ActivityTestRule` you can specify the activity that you would like to test.

Adding the following code in your test class:

```
@get:Rule
var activityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>
       = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)
```

Should specify the activity that you would like to use for testing.
See [Use Espresso with ActivityTestRule](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing#espresso-atr) for more details.

Comment: Not working, last added test class launched firstly, can you suggest a code with 2 activity with 2 rules.

Comment: @NeethuAnand [Here](https://github.com/android/testing-samples/blob/master/ui/espresso/BasicSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/espresso/BasicSample/ChangeTextBehaviorTest.java) you can find a full sample testing two activities in the same unit test, from the documentation.